# JOOQ No Connection configured Issue

Tags: java, mysql, jooq

I am insert a record to MySql using JOOQ , this is my code

```
if (f.getConnection()!=null) {
    UserRecord us = new UserRecord();
    us.setAccountId(UInteger.valueOf(accountId));
    us.setCode(code);
    us.setEnd(new java.sql.Date(end.getTime()));
    us.setStart(new java.sql.Date(start.getTime()));
    us.setPhoneNumberId(UInteger.valueOf(phnNUmberId));            
    us.store();
}
```

(f is database connection factory class)
It gives
    Exception in thread "main" org.jooq.exception.DetachedException: Cannot execute
    query. No Connection configured

But database connection is nut null , What can be the reason ?
(select queries are working with same connection)

Answer (score 12):

Your user record is not "attached" to that `Factory` (jOOQ 2.0, in more recent versions, it's called `Configuration`). You have two options:

```
// Attach the user record prior to calling "store"
f.attach(us);
us.store();

// Create a pre-attached user record:
UserRecord us = f.newRecord(Tables.USER);
// [...]
us.store();
```

If unattached, there's no way for jOOQ to discover what Factory (Configuration) should be used to store your record.